# SSRS Group by & duplicate rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

[enter link description here][1]I have dataset from SQL like below:

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGhbD.jpg)

In ssrs, i need the report like below:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arMl3.jpg)

I used the Table.Tried,

Option1: Applied Parent Row group for "Col1" ,child row group for "Col2"   Hide duplicates in "Col3"  based on "Col1" group.

Option 2:Applied Row group for "Col1" , Hide duplicates in "Col2" based on "Col1" group & Hide duplicates in "Col3"  based on "Col1" group.

Option 3: =iif(Previous(Fields!col.Value)=Fields!col.Value , true, false) in column level.

i could not get expected result with above option.please suggest me

Comment: This would by a grouping by Col1 with details left and right to the "header" (column), which I think isn't possible. Consider to place the merged cells column (Col1) left to the details.

Answer (score 0):

What you want like in your result picture isnt possible. You basically grouped Col1, Col2 and Col3 in one Tablix. Thats doesnt work.
You can group for example by Col1 and Col2, then you get

```
Test | A
Test | B
```

You can group by Col2 and Col3:

```
Test | X
Test | Y
Test | Z
```

If you group Col1 and Col2 and Col3 you get the whole table back, like nothing happened.

But you can group by Col1 and Col2 and aggregate (with Count) Col3. Like this:

```
Test | A | 3
Test | B | 3
```